# Is it possible to track a face on iOS using the camera?

Tags: ios, swift

I know I can recognize a face bounding box on iOS, but, I am wondering if it is possible once a face has been found to know for each frame that comes in if the face tracked is the same one I tracked in the previous frame.

This would allow me to handle multiple faces found in the frames and being able to know if each face is the same one as the previous frame...

As of now I only know how to track a face per frame without knowing if the face I am tracking is the same one from the previous frame.

Any input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See iOS 11's [VNDetectFaceLandmarksRequest and VNFaceObservation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision).

For older iOS, there are SDKs including [OpenCV](https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/face-recognition-with-opencv/#demo-facial-detection-and-recognition) and Microsoft's [Cognitive-Face-iOS](https://github.com/Microsoft/Cognitive-Face-iOS) and others if you search.

Comment: VNDetectedObjectObservation and VNTrackObjectRequest did the trick.